C# code, SendKeys.Send gets "Access denied..." error occasionally
I have a C# code, in which I need to run a very old vendor binary to ASCII conversion program, here is relevant part of my code:
C# code with SendKeys.Send "Access denied..."
These codes are run in the 30 min timer continuously. Everyday there are about 50 to 150 files needed to be converted, but once a day, the line that enters the file name gets an "Access denied..." error, just once, upon restarting my C# code, the conversion will resume just fine.
When I am in the office, it never breaks, it only breaks when I am out of the office. I adjusted the wait time before this line, but to no avail.
I am kind of out of my wit of how to fix this. Thank you for any advice and help.

You may try a different way of sending data to StandardInput. Below I'll show some different ways one can write to StandardInput and read from StandardOutput. The code has been tested with .NET Framework v4.8. At the end of the post is code for a Console App that I used for testing.
Note: In the code below, ensure that you change the responses to the desired values.
Add the following using directives

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

Option 1:
private void RunProcess(string exeFilename)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = exeFilename,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    using (Process p = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code
                Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //start
        p.Start();

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
        p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            //response for 1st prompt
            sw.WriteLine(@"C:\Temp\Test.txt");

            //response for 2nd prompt
            sw.WriteLine("n");

            //response for 3rd prompt
            sw.WriteLine("y");

            //response for 4th prompt
            //sw.WriteLine("y");
            sw.WriteLine("");
        }

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}


Option 2:
Note: Responses are placed into a List, and then a foreach loop is used to write to StandardInput.
private void RunProcess(string exeFilename)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = exeFilename,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    using (Process p = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code
                Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //start
        p.Start();

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
        p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output
        
        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            //provide values for each input prompt
            //ToDo: add values for each input prompt 
            List<string> responses = new List<string>() { @"c:\Temp\Test.txt", "n", "y", string.Empty };

            foreach (string resp in responses)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(resp);
            }
        }

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}

Option 3:
Note: This option reads from StandardOutput using a Task (or Thread). This allows one to read StandardOutput that doesn't end with a newline, as well as, output that does contain a newline. If the output of the .exe file doesn't end with a newline, try this option to see if it gives the desired output.
private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
private CancellationToken _token;

              ...

private async void ReadStandardOutput(Stream s, CancellationToken token)
{
    int bufferSize = 1024;

    int totalBytesRead = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = await s.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize, token);

        //add
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            //convert to string
            string output = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead).Trim();
            //Debug.WriteLine($"StandardOutput: '{output}'");
            Debug.WriteLine($"{output}");
        }
    }    
}

private void RunProcess(string exeFilename)
{
    //create new instance
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    //create reference
    _token = _tokenSource.Token; 

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = exeFilename,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    };

    using (Process p = new Process() { StartInfo = startInfo, EnableRaisingEvents = true })
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        p.Exited += (sender, e) =>
        {
            //cancel reading from StandardOutput
            _tokenSource.Cancel();

            Debug.WriteLine("Process has exited.");
        };
       

        //start
        p.Start();

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadStandardOutput(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream, _token));

        //Thread t = new Thread(() => ReadStandardOutput(p.StandardOutput.BaseStream, _token)) { IsBackground = true };
        //t.Start();

        //sleep to allow time for task/thread to start
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            //provide values for each input prompt
            //ToDo: add values for each input prompt 
            List<string> responses = new List<string>() { @"c:\Temp\Test.txt", "n", "y", string.Empty };

            foreach (string resp in responses)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(resp);
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();

        Debug.WriteLine("After p.WaitForExit");
    }
}



Usage:
RunProcess(@"C:\Temp\ConsoleInputTest.exe");


For testing, I created a Console App (.NET Framework) (name: ConsoleInputTest)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleInputTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> flagsDict = null;

            if (args.Length != 0)
            {
                //get command-line args and put them in a Dictionary
                 flagsDict = GetCommandLineArgs(args);
            }
            else
            {
                //create new instance
                flagsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                string filename = string.Empty;

                do
                {
                    //prompt user
                    Console.Write("Please enter filename: ");

                    //read input
                    filename = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (!File.Exists(filename))
                        Console.Error.WriteLine($"File doesn't exist ('{filename}'). ");

                } while (!File.Exists(filename));

                flagsDict.Add("filename", filename);

                string prompt2 = GetYesNoAnswer("Prompt2 - For testing, please enter 'n' for this prompt (default: y)");
                flagsDict.Add("prompt2", prompt2);

                string prompt3 = GetYesNoAnswer("Prompt3 - For testing, please press enter or enter 'y' for this prompt (default: y)");
                flagsDict.Add("prompt3", prompt3);

                string prompt4 = GetYesNoAnswer("Prompt4 - For testing, please press enter or enter 'y' for this prompt (default: y)");
                flagsDict.Add("prompt4", prompt4);
            }

            if (flagsDict != null)
            {
                //for testing, output arguments/input and values
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in flagsDict)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");
                }
            }
            
        }

        private static string GetYesNoAnswer(string message)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            do
            {
                Console.Write($"{message}: ");
                result = Console.ReadLine();

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
                    result = "y";

                if (result.ToLower() != "y" && result.ToLower() != "yes" && result.ToLower() != "n" && result.ToLower() != "no")
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid response. ");

            } while (result.ToLower() != "y" && result.ToLower() != "yes" && result.ToLower() != "n" && result.ToLower() != "no");

            return result;
        }

        private static void DisplayUsage()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat($"{Environment.NewLine}");

            sb.AppendFormat($"  Usage 1:{Environment.NewLine}");
            sb.AppendFormat($"  {System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.exe{Environment.NewLine}");

            sb.AppendFormat($"{Environment.NewLine}");

            sb.AppendFormat($"  Usage 2:{Environment.NewLine}");
            sb.AppendFormat($"  {System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.exe <flag> <value>{Environment.NewLine}");

            sb.AppendFormat($"{Environment.NewLine}");

            sb.AppendFormat($"  Flags: {Environment.NewLine}");

            sb.AppendFormat($"{Environment.NewLine}");

            sb.AppendFormat($@"  -filename: <filename> (ex: -filename: ""C:\My Folder\filename1.txt"") {Environment.NewLine}");

            sb.AppendFormat($@"  -prompt2: [y|n] (ex: -prompt2: n) {Environment.NewLine}");
            sb.AppendFormat($@"  -prompt3: [y|n] (ex: -prompt3: y) {Environment.NewLine}");
            sb.AppendFormat($@"  -prompt4: [y|n] (ex: -prompt4: y) {Environment.NewLine}");

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, string> GetCommandLineArgs(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> flagsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string currentFlag = string.Empty;

            //the following retrieves the command-line arguments
            //it handles values that contain spaces
            //such as 'C:\My Folder\filename1.exe'
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                //get flag
                //ex: '-f:'
                if (args[i].StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    //this keeps track of the current flag which
                    //is necessary in order to handle values that contain spaces

                    if (!args[i].EndsWith(":"))
                    {
                        //set value; if flag doesn't end with ':', add it
                        currentFlag = $"{args[i]}:";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //set value
                        currentFlag = args[i];
                    }

                    if (!flagsDict.ContainsKey(currentFlag))
                    {
                        //add to Dictionary
                        flagsDict.Add(currentFlag, string.Empty);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error: '{currentFlag}' already specified. A flag is only permitted to be specified once.");
                        Environment.Exit(-1);
                    }
                }
                else if (args[i] == "/?")
                {
                    DisplayUsage();
                }
                else
                {
                    //if no flag is specified, assume it's a filename
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentFlag))
                    {
                        currentFlag = "-f:"; //filename 
                        flagsDict.Add(currentFlag, args[i]); //add to Dictionary
                    }
                    else if (flagsDict.ContainsKey(currentFlag))
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(flagsDict[currentFlag]))
                            flagsDict[currentFlag] += " "; //add space

                        flagsDict[currentFlag] += args[i]; //set or update value in Dictionary
                    }
                }
            }


            return flagsDict;
        }
    }
}


Resources:

Process class
String Interpolation
Task class
Thread class

